# How to create program check PE file

Tags: c, portable-executable

I want to write a program to check if any file is in PE format using C? I have read and learned about PE files, I need to check two things:

1. DOS Header, MZ (45 5A)
2. PE header 50 45 00 00

Iam not good at coding, so it is difficult to code. I have tried the code. I use FILE * to read the file byte, the result is 0000000000905A4D, as opposed to what I see in HxD.

Can you help me? Please give me some specific instructions, or a link for me to follow.

Thank you so much
Here is my code, i tried read 2 byte, but fail :(

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int n,address;
 FILE *fptr;
 if ((fptr = fopen("Easy Keygen.exe","rb")) == NULL)
 {
  printf("error!");
 }

 fread(&n, 4,2,fptr);
 printf("address: %p ", n);
 fclose(fptr); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are running into a prime tripper-upper of a new programmer, called [little endian](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/big-endian-and-little-endian).

What this means essentially, is that your bytes will end up in the reverse order from that which you expect when you read some values as an integer. I think you might also be getting tripped up by fread as well. In order to read only two bytes, your fread call needs to be more like:

```
fread(&n,1,2,fptr);
```

The third argument to fread is the number of "elements" to read, and the second argument is the size of each element. So this fread call will read two elements, each of size 1 - two bytes.

An example of a program that might do what you're asking for for the DOS header (which by the way is 4D5A in big endian) might be:

```
short magic;
FILE* fptr;
if ((fptr = fopen("Easy Keygen.exe","rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("error!");
}
fread(&magic,1,2,fptr);
printf("magic value was 0x%x\n",magic);
```

This *should* print out that the magic value is **0x5a4d**. Again - the bytes will be backwards because integers (and pointers as well) are interpreted in **reverse order**. In order to actually confirm your check, you will need to compare to 0x5a4d NOT 0x4d5a.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I  got it and will edit it in my code
So what about the second option? How do I read PE headers? U can help me ?

Comment: A PE header is really no different from the MZ header that we've examined here. The sole difference is that instead of looking for 2 bytes, we're looking for four bytes instead. Additionally, we're looking for them in a different part of the file. In order to read the PE header in, you can use fseek to advance your FILE* pointer to where you expect the PE header to be, and then read in the 4 bytes into an integer. Once again, remember your little endian.

Comment: oh, nice. Before , i think i need add struct of PE header , okay. i try now, thanks you so much

Comment: No problem Levi - if your problem is answered don't forget to hit the check mark on the left of the answer so that we know you're content with the answer received. And if you have a new question, feel free to come back and ask some more :)